# babel vs babel-core vs babel-runtime

Tags: babeljs

My node webpack project uses three babel libraries. What's the difference between these and how are they being used?

```
"dependencies": {
  "babel-runtime": "^5.8.24"
}

"dev-dependencies": {
  "babel": "^5.8.23",
  "babel-core": "^5.8.23"
}
```

Comment: It's all in the docs if you look around: https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/api/, https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/runtime/, https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/

Comment: the runtime docs link leads to 404.

Comment: For such a widely used library the docs are pretty bad. The good stuff is however inline in the code, but if you don't know what you actually need to use it's useless.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

`babel-core` is the API. For v5 the `babel` package is the CLI and depends on `babel-core`. For v6, the `babel-cli` package is the CLI (the CLI bin command is still `babel` though) and the `babel` package doesn't do anything. `babel-runtime` I guess is just the runtime (polyfill and helpers) to support code that's already been transformed.

Comment: And one more question: what should I use in my project with webpack?

Comment: @just-boris see http://babeljs.io/docs/setup/#webpack and the note in the plugin's readme about peer dependencies. See also the link @ FelixKling posted for the optional runtime transformer.

Comment: For people who are interested in difference between `babel-runtime` and `babel-polyfill`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31781756/is-there-any-practical-difference-between-using-babel-runtime-and-the-babel-poly

Comment: @JMM, Recently, I just get confused with the dependencies, @babel/core and babel-core. What is the difference?

Answer (score 21):

TL;DR The things to compare here are:

1. babel (use for 5.x.x) vs babel-cli+babel-core (pick one for 6.x.x)
2. babel-polyfill (use for non-libraries) vs babel-runtime+babel-plugin-transform-runtime (use for libraries)

From https://babeljs.io/blog/2015/10/31/setting-up-babel-6:

> The babel package is no more. Previously, it was the entire compiler and all the transforms plus a bunch of CLI tools, but this lead to unnecessarily large downloads and was a bit confusing. Now we’ve split it up into two separate packages: babel-cli and babel-core.
>
> npm install --global babel-cli
>
> or
>
> npm install --save-dev babel-core
>
> If you want to use Babel from the CLI you can install babel-cli or if you want to use the Node API you can install babel-core.

babel-runtime just allows polyfills that don't pollute the global space, unlike babel-polyfill which pollutes your global space. From http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-runtime/:

> [babel-runtime] automatically polyfills your code without polluting globals. (This plugin is recommended in a library/tool)

If you use babel-runtime, you should also

`npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-runtime`

> In most cases, you should install babel-plugin-transform-runtime as a development dependency (with --save-dev) and babel-runtime as a production dependency (with --save).
>
> The transformation plugin is typically used only in development, but the runtime itself will be depended on by your deployed/published code.

Also, babel-runtime+babel-plugin-transform-runtime and babel-polyfill are generally mutually exclusive--meaning you should only use one or the other. From a comment here http://jamesknelson.com/the-six-things-you-need-to-know-about-babel-6/:

> You should be using either babel-polyfill or babel-runtime. They are mutually exclusive—unless of course you know what you are doing. But they are essentially the same thing. These are just helpers. babel-polyfill achieves the same goal by mutating globals whereas babel-runtime does so modularly. Unless you are developing a library, I’d recommend you use the polyfill.

Answer (score 1):

[The Six Things You Need To Know About Babel 6](http://jamesknelson.com/the-six-things-you-need-to-know-about-babel-6/) explained it quite well, to quote

> The babel npm package no longer exists. Instead, Babel has been split
>   into multiple packages:
>
> babel-cli, which contains the babel command line interface babel-core,
>   which contains the Node API and require hook babel-polyfill, which
>   when required, sets you up with a full ES2015-ish environment To avoid
>   accidental conflicts, make sure to remove any previous Babel packages
>   like babel, babel-core, etc. from your package.json, and then npm
>   uninstall them.