# Why babel package was divided into two separate packages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

I am new to React and was learning how to set up react environment from scratch. The confusion I faced when I was trying to install babel for my project. The question is why babel package was divided into two packages: babel-cli and babel-core since both plays vital role in the proper operation of BABEL itself and I have to install both anyways. Wasn't it better to install one babel package instead of two: babel-cli and babel-core.

Comment: This should answer your question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32544685/babel-vs-babel-core-vs-babel-runtime

Comment: @Hbarna, thank you for your provided link, I have read through and it says that if we want to use babel from cli we need to install babel-cli. Ok, I have installed @babel/cli but I get an error saying I need to install @babel/core as well. So, why need to divide one package into two and tell us "Now you need to install two package".

Comment: So that you don't have to install the CLI if you don't need it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read `babel-cli` source code you can see that it require `babel-core`. The babel-core is used to compile ES6 to backwards compatible version of JavaScript and more.
The `babel-cli` is just some command line to help you run `babel-core`.

But not all want to use babel-cli to just compile an ES6 file. Instead they may use some streaming build like `gulp` or `webpack`. They don't need `babel-cli` to use command, they only need `babel-core` to compile the code. So if you want to compile ES6 to backwards version of javascript, you must have `babel-core`. There you can use either `babel-cli` (for babel command) or write your own code use `babel-core` to convert or use other tool like `gulp`, `webpack`.

Comment: thank you very much for your great answer. I have a mere question how to use babel-core only to convert our code without babel-cli:)

Comment: @topGun https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-core you can read the guide here

Comment: last question, webpack and gulp do not need babel-cli because they have their own cli to be used with babel-core? Gosh, so difficult to be starter :)

Comment: @topGun , yes they have their own plugin like `gulp-babel` and `babel-loader` to use. So user only include plugin in their pineline and use their own command line.

Comment: @topGun I'm not quite sure about all case, maybe because of old version or something. But from `babel-loader` source code (webpack plugin), the code only use `babel-core`. So I can assume that maybe they use babel-cli for testing.