# babel-polyfill vs babel-plugins

Tags: babeljs, babel-polyfill

I am a bit lost in the Babel options / config. I want to use recent js features and compile (with webpack) to browser code.

What is the difference between [babel-polyfill](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/polyfill/) and [babel plugins](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/) with `babel-preset-env`?

Are they intended to work together?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Answer from [this article](https://medium.com/@jcse/clearing-up-the-babel-6-ecosystem-c7678a314bf3):

> The distinction between a `babel transform plugin` versus
>   `babel-polyfill / babel-runtime` **is whether or not you can
>   reimplement the feature today, in ES5**. For example, `Array.from` can
>   be rewritten in ES5 but there is nothing I can write in ES5 to add
>   arrow function syntax to JavaScript. Therefore, there is a transform
>   for arrow functions but none for `Array.from`. It will have to be
>   provided by a separate polyfill like `babel-polyfill`, or
>   `babel-runtime`.

---

As a side note, here is my current understanding of the babel eco-system.

`Babel` is a javascript compiler: it **parses**, **transforms** and **outputs transformed code**.

#### babel-core

- This is the **parse** and **output** parts.
- It does not do any transformation.
- It can be used from the command line or from a bundler (webpack, rollup and co.)

#### babel-polyfill / babel-runtime

- Acts on the **transform** part by prepending es5 javascript to your code to emulate **es2015+ functions** (like Object.assign).
- Relies on [Regenerator](https://medium.com/@jcse/clearing-up-the-babel-6-ecosystem-c7678a314bf3) (to polyfill [generators](https://github.com/facebook/regenerator))  and [core-js](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function%2A) (to polyfill all the rest).
- Difference between `babel-polyfill` and `babel-runtime`: the former defines global methods (and pollutes the global scope) whereas the latter transforms your code to make the same functionnality available as [explained in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31790138/2112538).

#### babel plugins

- **Transform** the code you wrote.
- `babel syntax / transform plugins`: parse and transform **es2015+ syntax** (like arrow functions) to convert it to es5.
- `babel-plugins-stage-x` (from stage-0 to stage-4): transform future javascript syntax which is not in the JS specs yet, starting at stage-0 (just an idea) down to stage-4 (will land in the `babel-plugins` soon).

#### babel-preset-env

- `babel-preset-env` determines the Babel plugins and polyfills needed for a specific environment.
- With no configuration, it will load all the plugins (including es2015, es2016 and es2017) required to transpile es2015+ to es5.
- With a `target` option, it loads only the plugins required to run on a specific target.
- With the `builtIn` option, it uses only the `babel-polyfill` which are not *built-in* the target.
- Does not work with `babel-transform-runtime` yet (as of nov. 2017). (see [this issue](https://github.com/babel/babel-preset-env/issues/246))

Comment: Would you like to update this answer since we are at 2021? I've been searching on Internet and there are little highly organized answers, so I think keep your answer up to date indeed help more people like me.

Comment: __babel-polyfill / babel-runtime__ > by prepending es5 javascript: What did you mean _prepending_?

Answer (score 3):

[babel-preset-env](https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/master/experimental/babel-preset-env) is a Babel preset meant to automatically set up [babel plugins](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/) and include the necessary [babel polyfills](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/polyfill/) based on a set of target environments checked against a [feature compatibility table](https://github.com/kangax/compat-table).

In order to make a **fully working ES2015+ environment** run on a **non-ES2015+ client**, simple code transpilation is sometimes not enough:

- **ES generators** are enabled using [regenerator](https://github.com/facebook/regenerator) library (provided by **babel-polyfill**)
- **Missing ES2015+ methods** (like `Promise`, `Map`, `Object.assign`...) are polyfilled with [core-js](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js) (provided by **babel-polyfill**, too)
- Any other **transpilable feature** is generated by standard babel plugins, often used trough pre-configured [babel-presets](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/)

So, back to your question, it's **babel-preset-env** that makes use of **babel-polyfill** and **babel plugins**.

Comment: Ok thanks. So what is the difference between polyfill and stage plugins?

Comment: thank you for your answer (I upvoted). This helped but I was still confused… So I read about that subject and made my own answer to summarise what I understood.